# Selecting Mutually Exclusive PC from a PCA Analysis in R

Tags: r, logistic, pca

I have run a PCA Analysis on some code and it produced a PCA analysis; however, I want to identify which PC are mutually exclusive and use them in a logistic regression.  According to the PCA analysis the first 5 PC results are significant; however if I use all 5 of them in a logistic model they become not significant (possible because they actually overlap but I can't tell)

I've extracted the first 5 PC and used them in a log model but I get a P-Value that isn't significant.  If I just use 1 PC I get a better answer but I want to identify which PC variables I can use in conjunction.

Call:
`glm(formula = Train.Target ~ PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4, family = binomial(), data = train.data)`

I get a result that basically says all P values are = 1.
If I use 1 PC (see below) I get an actual p-value

`train.data <- data.frame(Train = vacationpackage_train2, train.pca$x) train.data <- train.data[,1:55] logmodel6 <- glm(Train.Target ~ PC1, family = binomial(), train.data) summary(logmodel6)`

Identifying which PC variables in a PCA model are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me define $n$ as the number of observations in your dataset, and $p$ as the number of covariates you are working with. This way, your matrix of covariates is $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and your (binary) response variable is (with a little abuse of notation) $y\in\{0, 1\}^n$.

When you perform a principal component analysis you will get mainly two things as output.

1. The matrix of principal components:
   This matrix, formed by the eigenvectors of $X$, is  obtained in a way such that the first principal component has the largest possible variance, and each succeeding component has the highest possible variance under the constraint that it is orthogonal to the preceding components. You say that  you are keeping 5 principal components. This means that this matrix, let me call it $P$ will be a matrix of dimension $P\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times 5}$
2. The projection of your covariates matrix into the space generated by the principal components: This matrix, let me call it $T$, will be a matrix of dimension $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 5}$. And you are using this $T$ matrix in your logistic regression model.

Now, since the principal components are orthogonal, this means that there is no bit of information provided by the first PC that is also being provided by the second PC, or by any other PC, and in the same way, there is no bit of information provided by the second PC that is also being provided by other PC. In your words, all the components are mutually exclusive **by definition**

The principal components are also defined in a way that they maximize the variance of the matrix $X$. But this means that some PCs are not relevant for prediction, but are only relevant for describing the variance in $X$. And this fact explains why, although in your case, the first $5$ principal components are considered enough for explaining the variance of $X$, this does not mean that are the most relevant components for predicting the value of your response variable.

Comment: So how can you tell that that they aren't relevant for predicting the value of your response variable within the PCA itself?  Thanks for your explanation by the way!

Comment: Well, once you have performed the PCA and obtained the principal components, the general way of working is to keep some of the first PCs (because these are the PCs that explain most about your original matrix X), and among these components, you need to test which are significant for your model. For doing this there are many criteria, for example statistical inference (using p-values as you were doing) or subset selection.